# Why doesn't my regex match my string?

Tags: regex

I am trying to match

```
[140]  0.0-39.1 sec  62.5 MBytes  13.4 Mbits/sec  4.757 ms 59835/104450 (57%)
```

using Perl.

I wrote this regex:

```
    if($line =~/\[\d+]\s+(\d+.\d-\d+.\d)\s+sec\s+\d+.\d\s+MBytes\s+(\d+.\d)\s+Mbits/sec\s+(\d+.\d+)\s+ms\s+\d+\/\d+\s+\(\d+%\)/)
```

it won't match no matter what I do :(

Can you please help me?

Comment: `\[\d+]\s+(\d+.\d-\d+.\d)\s+sec\s+\d+.\d\s+MBytes\s+(\d+.\d)\s+Mbits\/sec\s+(\d+.\d+)\s+ms\s+\d+\/\d+\s+\(\d+%\)`

Comment: Have you considered using a regex debugging tool?

Comment: I get this error when I use your regex @Fabricator    :   Nested quantifiers before HERE mark in regex m/\[\d+]\s+(\d+.\d-\d+.\d)\s+sec\s+\d+.\d\s+MBytes\s+(\d+.\d)\s+Mbits/sec\s
+(\d+?? << HERE .\d+)\s+ms\s+\d+/\d+\s+\(\d+%\)/ at testparse.pl line 21.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to escape the `/` in `13.4 Mbits/sec`:

```
\[\d+]\s+(\d+.\d-\d+.\d)\s+sec\s+\d+.\d\s+MBytes\s+(\d+.\d)\s+Mbits\/sec\s+(\d+.\d+)\s+ms\s+\d+\/\d+\s+\(\d+%\)
```